# jQPlot pie chart - how to alter text color of pie slice labels

Tags: jqplot

I am using jQPlot to draw a pie chart.

How can I change the color of the text that appears on each  pie slice?  There does not appear to be an option to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just modified the top-level jqplot css that affects all text (as I wanted it all the same colour anyway).

Answer (score 4):

It is not really a good idea to modify the distributed jqplot CSS file, because that makes for poor maintainability (you have to re-apply your changes if you, or anyone else, ever upgrades).

Instead, I recommend overriding the CSS using CSS Specificity Rules (see the [Star Wars Version](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg)).

For example, given

```
<div id='myChart'; style="width:400px;height:300px;background-color:#eedd33">
</div>
```

You could define a CSS rule

```
#myChart
{
    color: Teal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to modify the given CSS file as it will modify all uses of the library.

You don't want to create a CSS rule for the entire chart container, as it will also apply the color to any legend or other text that will inherit it.

Instead, just modify the class jqplot uses for its data labels:   **.jqplot-data-label**

Use this:

```
$('.jqplot-data-label').css("color","white");
```

This way, only the data labels will change color.  All other text such as legend labels will not be changed.